# Adding Lists into A Dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary having its keys as extensions of each file in a directory. I want to add values to each key, but the number of values I want are two. First is the number of files with each extension and second, the list of the size of each file with that extension.

For example, `d={'py': 3,[23, 45, 67, 'PNG': 2,[345, 569]}`.

To do this, I first made a full-list that has its elements as a list having an extension and the size of every file, the first element, and the second element of the list respectively. My problem is something in adding lists of file size to each extension as values of it. How do I have to correct my code?

```
count=0
list_full=[]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for f in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(root, f)
        extension=fullname.split(".")[-1]
        size = os.path.getsize(fullname)
        print("The extension of " + fullname + "is : " + extension)
        
        list_full.append([extension,size])


list_first_half=[item[0] for item in list_full]

print("\nThe number of files with each extension is this:\n")
d={i:list_first_half.count(i) for i in list_first_half}
print(d)


for key in d:
    for item in list_full:
        if item[0]==key:
            d[key].append(item[1])




# if i[0]==key:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

or for key in d:
    listforD=[]
    for i in range(len(list_full)):
        if list_full[i][0]==key:
            listforD.extend(list_full[i][1])
            d[key].append(listforD)

# listforD.extend(list_full[i][1])
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you also include the output you got?

Comment: Please provide  the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555149/7403431) where you specified that you have

```
list_full=[['txt', 68], ['pdf', 832053], ['pdf', 57741123], ['PNG', 101397], ['pdf', 4785477], ['txt', 0], ['zip', 649], ['zip', 665], ['py', 922], ['py', 1446], ['py', 730], ['py', 650], ['py', 818], ['docx', 62079], ['docx', 112673], ['docx', 15881], ['docx', 14388], ['docx', 14522], ['docx', 15279], ['docx', 17097], ['docx', 783905], ['txt', 6], ['lnk', 2119], ['lnk', 2090], ['txt', 7], ['py', 104], ['txt', 650], ['PNG', 31596], ['py', 893], ['txt', 5], ['pdf', 104857], ['pdf', 6214790], ['txt', 0], ['txt', 0], ['txt', 0], ['py', 247], ['py', 647]]

d={'txt': 9, 'pdf': 5, 'PNG': 2, 'zip': 2, 'py': 9, 'docx': 8, 'lnk': 2}
```

you can do

```
for key, value in d.items(): # loop over d
    for e in list_full: # loop over list_full
        if key == e[0]: # check for matching doc types
            if type(d[key]) != list: # check if d[key] is already in desired format
                d[key] = [value, [e[1]]]
            else:
                d[key][1] += [e[1]]
```

Note, here you only take the doc types from `list_full` which are actually in `d`.

You get your desired output in `d`:

```
{'txt': [9, [68, 0, 6, 7, 650, 5, 0, 0, 0]],
 'pdf': [5, [832053, 57741123, 4785477, 104857, 6214790]],
 'PNG': [2, [101397, 31596]],
 'zip': [2, [649, 665]],
 'py': [9, [922, 1446, 730, 650, 818, 104, 893, 247, 647]],
 'docx': [8, [62079, 112673, 15881, 14388, 14522, 15279, 17097, 783905]],
 'lnk': [2, [2119, 2090]]}
```

Comment: How do I convert it to {'txt': 9, [68, 0, 6, 7, 650, 5, 0, 0, 0]],
 'pdf': [5, [832053, 57741123, 4785477, 104857, 6214790]],
 'PNG': [2, [101397, 31596],..... ?

Answer (score 0):

What I got is:

1. `list_full=[['txt', 68], ['pdf', 832053], ['pdf', 57741123], ['PNG', 101397], ['pdf', 4785477], ['txt', 0], ['zip', 649], ['zip', 665], ['py', 922], ['py', 1446], ['py', 730], ['py', 650], ['py', 818], ['docx', 62079], ['docx', 112673], ['docx', 15881], ['docx', 14388], ['docx', 14522], ['docx', 15279], ['docx', 17097], ['docx', 783905], ['txt', 6], ['lnk', 2119], ['lnk', 2090], ['txt', 7], ['py', 104], ['txt', 650], ['PNG', 31596], ['py', 893], ['txt', 5], ['pdf', 104857], ['pdf', 6214790], ['txt', 0], ['txt', 0], ['txt', 0], ['py', 247], ['py', 647]]`
2. `d={'txt': 9, 'pdf': 5, 'PNG': 2, 'zip': 2, 'py': 9, 'docx': 8, 'lnk': 2}`

And I want to print out `d={'txt':9,[68, 0, 650, ..., 0], ...}`